# Prove the transcendence of the number $e$

Tags: real-analysis

How to prove that the number $e=2.718281...$ is a transcendental number?   The truth is I have no idea how to do it.

If I can recommend a book or reference on this topic thank you.

There are many tests on the transcendence of $ e $?

I'd read several shows on the transcendence of $ e $

Comment: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/Herstein%20Beweis%20der%20Transzendenz%20der%20Zahl%20e.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try Michael Spivak's *Calculus*. I find it amusing that he would prove the transcendence of $ e $ in a calculus textbook.

Comment: I thought the same exact thing!  And he also devotes an entire chapter to the mere transcendence of $\pi$.

Comment: Oh... I didn't realize that he also proved the transcendence of $ \pi $ in the same book. It is a beautiful book.

Answer (score 3):

Your might be interested in the [Lindemann-Weierstrass-theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Transcendence_of_e_and_.CF.80), which is useful for proving the transcendence of numbers, e.g., $\pi$ and $e$.  If you read further, you'll see that the transcendence of both $\pi$ and $e$ are direct "corollaries" of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem.

Indeed, $e^x$ is transcendent if $x$ is algebraic and $x \neq 0\,$ (by the Lindemann–Weierstrass theorem).

A sketch of a (much) more elementary proof is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Sketch_of_a_proof_that_e_is_transcendental).

Answer (score -1):

I realize that amWhy already gave one answer: the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).  I don't know how to prove this... to be frank it is over my head.  But in general it states that in the equation:
$$e^a = b$$
If $a\ne 0$ is algebraic then $b$ is transcendental. The contrapositive is also true: if $b$ is algebraic then $a$ must be transcendental. Obviously $a=0,b=1$ has to be an exception.

Take that on faith for a moment. Like I said, I cannot prove the L-W theorem but I welcome you to research it.

If you ask whether or not $\ln(2)$ is algebraic or transcendental, take note that $e^{\ln(2)}=2$ is algebraic, and you can conclude that $\ln(2)$ is transcendental.

Similarly, you asked if $e$ itself was algebraic or transcendental. That is easy. $e^1 = e$ by definition. The power is algebraic therefore $e$ is transcendental. This is not circular reasoning. It rests squarely on the truth of the Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem: for *any* non-zero algebraic power, $e^a$, whatever that may be, is transcendental.

If you ever see a [proof for the transcendence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_number#Sketch_of_a_proof_that_e_is_transcendental) of $e$ more complicated than the one I just gave, I assure you it is just a proof for a special case of the L-W theorem. The general case proof would suit you better.

Likewise, take [Euler's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_identity): $e^{i\pi} = -1$.  The result is algebraic, therefore the power $i\pi$ is transcendental. But we already know $i$ to be algebraic, so it is the $\pi$ that is transcendental. This is how you prove the transcendence of $\pi$.

I would also like to mention a theorem that hasn't been mentioned yet: the [Gelfond-Schneider theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem).  It states that:
$$a^b$$
is always transcendental if:

- $a$ is algebraic and $a\ne 0,1$, **and**
- $b$ is algebraic **and** irrational

Numbers such as $2^{\sqrt{2}}$ are proven transcendental in this way.

We can also prove that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is transcendental as a consequence of the G-S theorem, because it is simply the square root of $2^{\sqrt{2}}$. The square root of a transcendental number is still transcendental.

I, personally, do not know of any other helpful theorems. But then I am new to transcendental number theory.  Good luck.